# Macro in VBA, bold text > *bold text*; italic > _italic_ (WhatsApp purpose)

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a macro in vba to do what the title says (I think it's pretty clear). I don't know which functions to use.

This is what I am looking for (partial):

```
Sub FormatForWhatsapp()
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = "*^&*"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Font.Italic = True
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = "_^&_"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

My problem is 1) I need a native code and not the Office "Find" Function. 2) I also need a code that does the opposite action for reformatting back to word.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I think it's pretty clear"  - nope.

Comment: What isn't clear?

Comment: What is a "native code" exactly?

Comment: It means I prefer not to use the Find function but a function that I could use on different platforms. But it's just my preference

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code for the Macros! Just make View Makros and then edit and paste my code in!

**Bold für Whatsapp:**

```
Sub bold()
'
' bold Makro
' Wahtsapp bold
'
' Tastenkombination: Strg+b
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "*" & ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 & "*"
End Sub
```

*Italic für Whatsapp:*

```
Sub Italic()
'
' Italic Makro
' Whatsapp Italic
'
' Tastenkombination: Strg+i
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "_" & ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 & "_"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! But I am looking for a script that locates bold or italic text and adds them.